# Проблема с рендерингом в дважды вложенных формах в Rails с cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Всем привет! Использую Rails 6, gem cocoon + vanilla js ([код взял отсюда](https://github.com/oddcamp/cocoon-vanilla-js)). Делаю создание тестов и на одной странице должны создаваться одновременно также вопросы и ответы. Проблема заключается в неправильном отображении при добавлении полей (скриншоты). Само добавление работает корректно, проблема есть именно с рендерингом. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где косяк.

Изначальная форма
[image: Изначальная форма]

При добавлении еще одного ответа (ожидалось, что поле появится снизу)
[image: Добавление вопроса]

При добавлении еще одного вопроса (ожидалось, что появится также поле для ввода первого ответа)
[image: Добавление ответа]

Форма для тестов:

```
=render 'shared/errors', object: @test

=form_with model: [:teacher, @test], local: true do |f|
  =f.number_field :author_id, class: 'hidden'
  =f.number_field :article_id, class: 'hidden'

  .mb-3.add-questions
    p
      | Add questions:
    .mb-3
      =f.fields_for :questions do |q|
        =render 'teacher/questions/question_fields', f: q
      =link_to_add_association 'Add one more question', f, :questions, partial: 'teacher/questions/question_fields'

  =f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-outline-success btn-lg mb-4'
```

Файл '_question_fields':

```
.mb-3.row
  .col-sm-2.col-form-label
    =f.label :title, 'Title'
  .col-sm-10.col-form-label
    =f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'

=f.fields_for :answers do |a|
  =render 'teacher/answers/answer_fields', f: a

=link_to_add_association 'Add one more answer', f, :answers, partial: 'teacher/answers/answer_fields'
```

Файл '_answer_fields':

```
.mb-1.row
  .col-sm-1
  .col-sm-2.col-form-label
    =f.label :content, 'Enter content'
  .col-sm-8.col-form-label
    =f.text_field :content, class: 'form-control'
  .col-sm-1.col-form-label
    =f.check_box :correct, {class: 'form-check-input'}, true, false
```